# Why change fonts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Why did the fonts change? I see **Segoe UI** and **Cascadia** for code, but **Cascadia mono** looks really bad to me (W10E, Firefox, 90%, 75pi screen).

Why the change? Can I revert just for me?

Comment: With a userscript you can revert: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364268/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates

Comment: And here is the cross-site duplicate for the why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1

Comment: @rene Thank god someone made this - the new fonts are truly horrible

Comment: You cannot revert it just for you, because a profile setting isn't a viable option? I wish SE would implement that.

Comment: I actually think it's slightly harder to read, at least the way it's rendered for me.

Comment: @akuzminykh: The text is being rendered with grayscale anti-aliasing here on Firefox. Might be a clue. Text on the main site seems to render with subpixel anti-aliasing as expected and looks just as good in Segoe as it does on my own site.

Comment: this is actually painful to read

Comment: The difference between mrn as in m ( em ) and rn (arr en) The difference between Il as in I (eye) and l (ell) The difference between 0O O (oh) and 0 (zero) The word pom porn should not look the same. dahe, d and h should have a tall masts relative to a and e. The brain draws a flat line over the tops of the letters, so tall letters should stick out. There should be at least 1 pixel of whitespace between ff ll I'll and ill should be obviously different. o0O should be obviously different.Capital (eye) I should be taller than lower case (ell) l as in Il. New font fails on each count.

Comment: I'm mystified as to how this much effort is put into changing fonts, when the l and I chars remain like this

Comment: Most of these actually don't look bad [in Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZAWS.png), @EricLeschinski , but the kerning for rn is still bad. I would actually say that the inconsistency between the fonts is *not* a good thing.

Comment: I will admit, I like Cascadia as the font choice for code. I use it in my IDEs and CLIs a lot so it's nice to have a familiar one. I do know some prefer others, but at least for me *that* is a welcome change. I think the biggest "problem" I'm going to have is that work on mutliple OSes every day, and the font looks very different on my Desktop (Linux) to my laptop (Windows) to my phone (Android), and I haven't turned on my Chromebook yet today... Maybe I should just pick up an M1 mac too just to make my head hurt more?

Comment: The letter spacing feels wider, too

Comment: bad decisions are bad decision, everybody should have the possibility to decide, what best for him

Comment: I like it, don't change it back. Sometimes newer cheese tastes better.

Comment: Arial is a hideous font that deserves to die.

Comment: @stuartd that may be the case, though, it is at least better than sergio ui.

Comment: I just feel the font-weight is too high when it's Cascadia. I'm fine with the font.

Comment: TBF Most of the time I saw the word "Pom" on the old design I had to double take and for ages I thought @Larnu was Lamu (until I saw them correct someone on this). So this isn't some new issue

Comment: IMHO it's an improvement on my Linux Mint and OSX devices. All the examples @EricLeschinski posted above look exactly as they should to me.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave It's Chrome browser on Linux that got broken by the changes.  I checked things on Windows, Mac and android and things are all correct.  They have a blog post about all this and explain why it's hard, since Fonts and the code between browser and monitor pixel are extremely copyrighted.  So it's an issue of Linux is open source, while Zune and Koolaid products are not. (They use money from sale-price of the service to pay people to obfuscate fonts working with the monitor companies).  Don't Copy That Floppy!  You wouldn't download a car....

Comment: It's quite hard to know if people are complaining about the same thing without screenshots. One person could have a text rendering issue, one person could have a missing font and another might just not like the font. It would be helpful to be able to rule out other issues so we know we're on the same page.

Comment: @Weeble Well the need to change the fonts is what I asked. The reasons do not matter; if someone wants to solve a rendering issue, that person can ask another question.

Comment: Over here on Windows this looks disgusting to my eyes at least

Comment: On my private linux machine, it seems acceptable (no Ubuntu font, not sure which one, might be liberation), on windows machine for work looks worse than ever imaginable.

Comment: Gah, the text is actually _smaller_ than any other site (on Windows). Even worse in the notifications... I'm sitting about 2ft away from my 49" ultrawide and I might need to zoom for SO (and only for SO)... WTF? [SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zydBK.png) [Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUtkW.png) (for comparison)

Comment: And for completeness, [SO with userscript fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeJ2r.png)

Comment: On Windows, 
The font is too light (at its current size); couldn't a better sans font be found on Google Fonts? 
The code font is too bold.

Comment: Simply looks horrible on Windows. Stack Overflow seems to have overlooked that some people seriously disliked SegoeUI and wanted to replace with the normal Tahoma (including myself). I even landed on SO after a Google search and took quite a bit of time to realize that I was seeing SO instead of some other forum copying SO, because of the funky fonts it has now.

Comment: My main problem on Windows is the barely visible minus signs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364274/vote-count-minus-signs-not-readable-in-segoe-ui

Comment: @stuartd: Arial is the one true font of which all others are but shadows...

Comment: *...everybody should have the possibility to decide...* @nbk Internet browsers used to let people do that. Firefox still has a setting that lets you use your own fonts instead of the ones chosen by the web site but as far as I can tell it's the only one still doing that. Chrome, Safari, and Edge let you pick default fonts but don't have the option of always using them no matter what.

Comment: @BSMP o wrote that everybody should have the choice to select the Design, forcing, i know how i can change the font, but that is not hwat i wanted, keep the old amake a new or two and let the people decide like with the black design.

Comment: @nbk "let the people decide" How exactly should it be done? Anyway, I thought I had commented with saying that on my system the bold text has too much weight in my opinion, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Trilarion the same as with the black design, people candecide if they use the "old" white design or the "newer" black one, nobody was forced to do so, so why the s.... with the fonts(btw, i use windows)

Comment: When entering or editing a question's title, g's and q's look the same as the bottom parts seem to get cut off. Win10/Chrome

Comment: @IanKemp Calling the OP an "illiterate" is not kind. I get your point, but seems like you are speaking out of immense frustration.

Comment: @stuartd Have you heard of font's rights ? It's terrible, and discriminating to ask for some font's death. Furthermore it survived this long for a reason.

Comment: @Soleil _it survived this long for a reason_ - and that reason is solely backwards compatibility. Quite honestly I hate Times New Roman more than MS Arial, but I'd be happy to see them both.. um.. retired.

Comment: Cascadia Mono looks too thick on my display, not sure why they made it that way.... I too would prefer the old font

Comment: I'm on a MBP, using an external 4K monitor. I think the Apple system-native fonts look amazing. I didn't even know what I was missing! I LOVE the change.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### Why?

As [Aaron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey) puts it on the announcement post [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048):

> ... [O]ur original font stack used Arial across macOS, iOS, and Windows. Arial was first created in 1982, and has served the web well for decades. But technology moves on. Modern system typefaces look better on both new high DPI screens, and old screens alike. Apple’s San Francisco and Microsoft’s Segoe both look great on retina displays, have more expressive weights, and improve readability across all contexts. With more weights, we can have better hierarchy.

I've no idea what the above all means but it is impressive and backed by no less than Github.

In some answers on the announcement post as well as in [Custom Fonts User Script: Revert or Improve the Font Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364268) you'll find both userscripts and/or userstyles to undo the cheese move.

Some wonder in the comments when `IF` was invented and when we will get rid of that. [`IF` was part of Lisp and Algol](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9745/11811) which dates backs to 1958. I assume `IF` will be abolished in the next 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: The reasoning is that it looks better on modern screens, and that arial is for older boomer screens. But that's not really the case, because new displays with new video cards are still making it unreadable.

Comment: Honestly, I kinda like the new font. It looks nice.

Comment: I wonder when the if-statement was invented. Maybe we should get rid of that too..

Comment: The only thing this new font does well is make clearer the difference between rnicrosoft and microsoft :)

Comment: Not for some of us, @10Rep . The font is OS dependant, and Ubuntu (the font) still has kerning (keming) issues. *Fortunately* most users aren't on Linux, so hopefully I'll stop being called "Lamu" now... I can dream, right? :)

Comment: @Larnu the r and n in your name are slightly easier to tell apart. for what it's worth. But many people seem to be against the font change, so it might not last long :).

Comment: yeah, i mean, i had to read that comrnent twice before i realized the difference

Comment: *"so it might not last long"* I think this might be one we have to live with @10Rep ; like question upvotes being worth 10 rep instead of 5.

Comment: I suspect the real reason why is this is the most they could get done in a single sprint.

Comment: change for the sake of change is still change

Comment: Along with the if statement, we should also abolish the `return` statement in programming languages. I mean, come on, returning text? That's SO 1980's!

Comment: What? People still code? That's so old school. I thought we were beyond that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't see an announcement and was quite confused about the change. I don't hate it, but it was a surprise.

Comment: As a linux user using the system fonts is great, the distro I use switched over to Inter and everything is nice and clean :)

Comment: The bold "Why" seems a bit too bold to me. Are there already Markdown equivalents of the more expressive weights?

Comment: @KevinB "change for the sake of change is still change" But it's only a change of appearance. The content is still the same, as good or bad as it is.

Comment: @Trilarion: You can't express different weights in HTML without using class names so I doubt there'd be a Markdown equivalent. On my site I use semibold across the board.

Comment: @Trilarion the "Why" is an H3. I can't make it any bolder for you ....

Comment: @10 Rep: Why would video cards have anything to do with this? An RTX 3090 is going to render ClearType the same way onboard graphics from the mid-2000s or Intel's integrated graphics would. This is just about screens with high or normal resolutions.

Comment: @10Rep All hail great [tag:R], where you (almost) don't use `return` and `if` is frowned upon.

Comment: @BoltClock So this "With more weights, we can have better hierarchy." is kind of moot. There is currently no way to have better hierarchy by more weights in posts.

Comment: @Trilarion: Yeah, it's moot as long as the different weights aren't actually put to use by the design system.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm just emphasising that this "new technology" still makes it look bad.

Comment: @Scratte If statement is a founding element, to build a function (in the set theory sense, ie., an a association). One can absolutely work outside Peano or ZFC, or without types. But all that is a point of view; one can see types in c and if in uples and axiom of choice behind that. Feel free to write your own language to fit your needs.

Comment: @Soleil Scratte just mimicked very successfully the logic of the company on this case  (something is old so it's bad). But you got me hooked. Is there any practically usable programming language there without any form of conditional if-like statement? Please understand I'm more a practical programmer.

Comment: @Trilarion I get it. It was a great response. One can imagine a set of uples (or a map in c++) of pairs of functions <args->bool, args->void>, if the first result is true, the second function is executed. Semantically there is no if, logically it is here. I think with the proper rewriting rules (compiler's logic) one can write a program this way. But, on the CPU, the ifs are still present. The if does not go away semantically. It's a way to present the premisses and context. The same way we can see a first order function (injection,surjection, one-to-one) as a set of if-then.

Comment: @Trilarion The problem with a program made of just a set of map<f,g> (g,f functions), is the readability for the human.

Comment: The article from [Mark Otto](https://markdotto.com/2018/02/07/github-system-fonts/) is from 2018, has nothing changed in this time?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler we had a pandemic since but that is probably as relevant as the article.  If you go looking for counter arguments, I'm sure you'll find one or two.

Comment: Why not just honor the user's setting for the default font in the browser?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried Wingding once as default font. Your mileage may vary ...

Comment: "*I've no idea what the above all means*" It means Aaron doesn't like Arial, basically. It all revolves around the opinion-based phrase "look better".

Comment: "If you go looking for counter arguments, I'm sure you'll find one or two." I guess one could be that now more cases have to be supported. You never know how something looks on the users screen but now even less. If people have an UI issue it might be even more complex to even reproduce. There might have been a solution with a single font possible. Something like the average of what Microsoft, Apple and Linux are using.

Comment: Font change on StackOveflow sucks. Where we could rely on a consistent 90 char before code generated a scroll bar, that has now been reduced to 84 characters. The font change has caused many old posts to now scroll. We have lost functionality as the result.

Comment: Comments as bug report / feature request also sucks but you don't hear me complaining @DavidC.Rankin ....

Answer (score 33):

**I don't care.**

I'm usually one for piling on anything SO does that I don't like, but this just seems so trivial. I understand every change is going to bother someone, but this one's a big "meh" for me.

If any other passer-by feels the same, they can leave their upvotes (or downvotes) here.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't care. I didn't care too much about the line height change (my only problem was the new code box ui). But IDK which OS you are using, but Segoe UI is literally the hardest font to read (at least for me).

Comment: **Didn’t ask.**

Comment: Take a page from rick and morty episode: pickle-rick in therapy, where he says: "I'm a scientist, when I don't like something about the world, I change it".

Comment: How do you mean, "Didn't ask"? There's a question at the top of the page.

Comment: I think it looks better now for what it's worth.

Comment: You're totally right. This is so trivial and complaining about this seems quite pedantic, I for one didn't even notice the change.

Comment: I think it's great some of you don't experience headaches when reading the new font. That doesn't however improve my situation.

Comment: Wanted to throw in that [tuning ClearType on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1337898/how-to-reset-the-font-in-windows-10/1338159#1338159) *measurably* improved the look and readability of fonts on SE for me on my machine after the font change. If anyone is having trouble and hasn't tried this yet (and doesn't have CrearType disabled intentionally), you should give it a try.

Comment: @zcoop98 zero effect unfortunately.

Answer (score 25):

I could revert thanks to this script js for Greasemonkey (on firefox) or Tampermonkey (on Chrome):

- [custom fonts 1.2.1 with original fonts](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/35c237ee02015b60d643f61a6f2570a1/raw/f3b6444ac77fea76dc4f1ff91914983b45381f07/custom-fonts-1.2-arial.user.js)
- [custom fonts 1.2.1, with Roboto + Roboto Mono](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/6587a7fb499a43e72d4ec24f4dc42df0/raw/22c095b716f7dca88ea9cd5f985b4d5c47cdcc97/custom-fonts-1.2.1-roboto.user.js)
- [custom fonts 1.2.1](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/custom-fonts.user.js)

**I think also that instead of any `Cascadia Mono`, they meant `Cascadia Code Light`** or so, which is IMHO a lot more appropriate because of its ligatures and readability (try those with each):

```
iI 1 lL  oO0  rn m  __global__ <= --> <==
```

(from https://stackapps.com/questions/8932/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates)

Comment: Awesome! Whew, could not focus with those fonts. First link worked great on FF for Linux!

Comment: Thanks! This saved script saved me. For reference, [here](https://hakonhagland.github.io/fonts/may-2021/example.html) is a comparison of the fonts on my machine (Ubuntu 21.04, Google Chrome). I strongly prefer the *"Before font change"* example

Comment: Honest question: Do you write rewrite website styles for all websites or just Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Hynes probably best to ask the person who wrote it (see the stackapps link at bottom)

Comment: @Hynes if you look at the script, it works on the websites matching one the expressions.

Comment: Thank you @Soleil You saved my day. I hated the new fonts.

Comment: Oh wow, thank God they did not actually use `Cascadia Code Light`. Font ligatures for programming? That's just a nightmare for my eyes.

Answer (score 24):

Not trying to be insulting,  **I thought my rendering had gone wrong**, that I needed to check a setting somewhere in my OS.

I wasn't thinking about wether I liked it or not, I actually thought something was broken, it looks very sharp, jagged (sorry, not a designer, dont know the proper terms) and found it harder to read. And I'm working on a Mac, which often shows font nice.

Knowing it was intended is a little relieve, guess I'll give it a go, see if I get used to it. But I've been taught to keep an eye out for a first feeling when there is a design change :)

Comment: It's new Copyrighted font-set issues and regressions.  You have to say what version of browser you're using, what version of Apple OS (if it's more than 18 months old you have to buy a new one with the fonts, because you know how it goes it's earnings season).  Yet another variable is monitor settings like tint, gaussian and other pixel rendering steps.  There are settings like noise, gamma, sharpness, contrast, color.  For me the problem bringing me here was copyrighted font sets on Linux Chrome.  Work-around now is tampermonkey and forcing a different font set that's compatible with Linux.

Comment: It's a modern Macbook, using up to date firefox. About everything else is left standard as I care little about all those things, I just need it to program :)

Comment: You're in luck, there's like 90 billion lines of code to program and reprogram, between the keystrokes on your keyboard and pixels on your monitor.

Comment: Given your description it’s likely that something on your system *is* broken, since the new font should render absolutely crisp and smooth without any issues whatsoever (nothing “sharp” or “jagged”) on a current Mac.

Comment: Topics and comments are fine (now), it was mainly the 'hot questions' parts. Again, it could be the getting used to part as it already reads easier, but I felt broken the first time I checked. Could be because it's a very thin font.

Comment: @EricLeschinski If you don't have the "copyrighted font sets" it eventually falls back to `sans-serif`, which is the sans serif font you can choose yourself in your browser settings. So if that's bad, it's your own damn fault; don't go blaming others.

Comment: I disagree, its the designers responsibility to choose a font that is reasonable available :)

Comment: I actually think this is an improvement on macOS. The new fonts are better readable, "m" and "rn" no longer look the same. I just tested Firefox, and it looks the same there as in Safari. You might want to try to clear your cache.

Comment: @EricLeschinski macOS upgrades are free. You don't "buy new ones". That's Windows. The font used comes with all versions of macOS and iOS since 2015, so the only reason not to have it is not having upgraded the OS in 6 years, which would mean you're running an OS that is no longer supported and gets no security patches.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Many of us are open-source developers trying to maintain alternatives to these paid-systems you refer to, that are depreciated, sunsetted, then as last resort obfuscated then force-obsoleted on a schedule [I can point you to the court cases], so that stuff stops working, and when they do, as 300 thousand of you noted on May 10.  A fraction of you spend thousands on a new rig, to fix the problem right now without any coding skill.  Font sets and the 900 billion lines of copyrighted code there is a landfill fire, and I will complain about it until our star inflates to a red giant.

Comment: @EricLeschinski I agree with you on planned obsolescence. But I don't know what your beef with copyright is. If copyright didn't exist, we wouldn't have so much open-source software. I certainly would keep all my sources secret if there were no copyright. Copyright is a very good thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can copyright be used as a mechanism to create money without creating intellectual property?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tamoj84j64I

Comment: Thought I was crazy. Just took a vaccine shot and got some pretty bad fever. Thought my vision went bad :D But I agree this feels too sharp to me, and prefer the old font so far.

Answer (score 5):

Reposting my userstyle from the meta SE question:

This should fix both sans-serif and monospace. It also fixes hardcoded fonts within textareas and codeblocks that don't use the font variables for some reason. This should work in both Stylus (tested) and Stylish (untested).

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com"),
domain("mathoverflow.net") {
body {
    --ff-sans: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    --ff-mono: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
}

code, .s-prose code, pre.s-code-block, textarea.wmd-input, textarea#wmd-input, .full-diff .content {
    font-family: var(--ff-mono);
}

.top-bar, .topbar-dialog, #user-menu, .topbar-dialog .header h3 a, .topbar-dialog .pinned-site-editor-container .remove-pinned-site-link a, .topbar-dialog .modal-content .message-text h4 {
    font-family: var(--ff-sans) !important;
}
}
```

(https://gist.github.com/SuperStormer/60a5e5c7e9549e9ed865a579df6f11be)

Comment: How can I use this with Safari?

Comment: @SilentK There's this [stylish port](http://sobolev.us/stylish/), but I have no idea if it works or not.

Comment: [There's no good reason to use Stylish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish#Privacy_issues) over stylus

Comment: @Zoe I agree, but Safari doesn't have a stylus port afaik.

Comment: Sooooo use a better browser instead of installing an extension that's known malware

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chrome extension that can help users customize code fonts. The earliest it was used to fix translation problems, but I found that another feature of it can also be used to customize code fonts. I hope it will be helpful to those who are keen to improve fonts.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-translation/nefkkabmejdacaifhjoinegmoggdbgee

Answer (score 2):

## [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh)

I have a custom-tailored Chrome extension to bring back the old fonts:

⭐ **[GET THE CHROME EXTENSION](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh)** ⭐

- Reverts text fonts to **Arial** and code fonts to **Consolas**
- ... other customizable settings

  - *turn off everything else if you only need to revert the fonts*

This was originally developed to revert the [formatting changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change) (specifically the line height change) introduced in August 2020, but has since been extended to support other revertable changes as well.

[image]

I added the option to revert fonts back in May, but didn't get around being lazy till now and finally decided to post this. Hopefully people are still searching for easy solutions to the new fonts